# Very simple question about ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

If $A$ is a commutative unital ring, $I$ is an ideal of $A$, and $a \in A$, then I know that
$$aI=(a)I$$
where $aI=\{ax : x \in I\}$ and $(a)I$ is the ideal product of the principal ideal $(a)$ and $I$.

Is there a generalization of this for a subset $S\subseteq A$?

Many thanks!

Comment: $(a)I$ What does it mean ? Do you mean $(a)=aA$ ?

Comment: $(a)I$ is the ideal product (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28ring_theory%29#Ideal_operations) of the principal ideal $(a)$ and $I$ :)

Comment: Well, if you define $SI=\{sx| s\in S ,x\in I \}$ then you can see that $SI$ need not be an ideal.

Comment: So, how do you define $SI$ ?

Comment: Well that's my question I suppose, is there a way to fix this

Comment: if you define $SI=\{\Sigma s_ix_i \}$ i.e all possible sums then it becames a ring.

Comment: @mesel Oop, I thought it was *show that* not *know that*

Comment: @mesel: indeed it does - but that doesn't help the situation I don't think :S

Comment: Let $\langle S\rangle$ be the ideal generated by $S$. Then $\langle S \rangle I$ is defined to be $\{\sum_{k=1}^n s_ki_k, s_k \in \langle S\rangle, i_k \in I\}$. This is indeed an ideal. It is the same as the ideal generated by $SI = \{si | s \in S, i \in I\}$. You should verify all this!

Comment: @MikeMiller: Great! Thank you, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for! :)

Comment: @user188071 You should check all the details and post them as an answer, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mike Miller, I now know what it is I want to prove...

**Theorem.** If $A$ is a commutative unital ring, $I$ is an ideal of $A$, and $S\subseteq A$, then

$$(S)I=(SI)$$

where $SI=\{si:s\in S, i \in I\}$.

*Proof.* The ideal $(S)I$ is, by definition, the smallest ideal of $A$ containing $\{xi :x \in (S), i \in I\}$.

Hence, in particular, $SI\subseteq (S)I$ and so $(SI)\subseteq (S)I$.

Conversely, if $\sum_kx_ki_k\in (S)I$, then, as $(SI)$ is an ideal, $\sum_kx_ki_k\in (SI)$.

This completes the proof.

Comment: Great!${}{}{}{}$